# How to get first elements of each list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

i need help working on a list:
i have a list like this

```
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 3],[10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

how do I get the first element of all the list within the list.

desired output:

```
1
3
7
10
```

Comment: ```output = [lst[0] for lst in input_list]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just iterate as it were a flat list

```
lists = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 3],[10, 11, 12, 13]]
 
for l in lists:
   if l != []:
     print(l[0])
```

Comment: thank you, do you have an idea, how i can put the out put in a list or array like ['1', '3', '7', '10'] or {'1' , '3', '7', '10'}

Comment: @Noblesomto initialize a list with ```firsts = []``` before the for loop and replace the print statement in the code with ```firsts.append(l[0])```